# PHP - sort/order an array by timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

Why I am getting 0 instead values from the database? What I am doing wrong if I give `$_POST['dataType'] === 'start'`. I never call a multiple DB select request. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATED:**

```
if(isset($_POST['dataType'])){
switch ($_POST['dataType']) {
    case 'start':
        $data_type = 'pictures, videos, audio, documents';
        break;
    case 'picture':
        $data_type = 'pictures';
        break;
    case 'video':
        $data_type = 'videos';
        break;
    case 'audio':
        $data_type = 'audio';
        break;
    case 'document':
        $data_type = 'documents';
        break;
    default:
        $data_type = '';
}


if (!empty($data_type)) {
    $userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_SESSION['userId']);
    if ($_POST['dataType'] !== 'start')
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $data_type . " WHERE user_id = " . $userId;
    else {
        $sql_picture = "SELECT * FROM pictures WHERE user_id = " . $userId . " ORDER BY upload_time";
        $sql_videos = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE user_id = " . $userId . " ORDER BY upload_time";
        $sql_audio = "SELECT * FROM audio WHERE user_id = " . $userId . " ORDER BY upload_time";
        $sql_documents = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE user_id = " . $userId . " ORDER BY upload_time";
    }

    // Check connection
    if ($connect->connect_error) {
        mysqli_close($connect);
        echo 1;
    }
    else {
        if ($_POST['dataType'] !== 'start'){
            $result = $connect->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $indexOfSuggests = 0;
                $data = array();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $public = $row['public'];
                    $link = $row['link'];
                    $upload_time = $row['upload_time'];
                    $data[$indexOfSuggests] = array($id, $user_id, $name, $public, $link, $upload_time);
                    $indexOfSuggests++;
                }
                $result->free();
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
            else {
                echo 0; // keine ergebnisse
            }
        }
        else {
            $indexOfSuggests = 0;
            $new_index;
            $collectData = array();
            for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++){
                $indexOfSuggests = $new_index;
                if($i == 0)
                    $sql = $sql_picture;
                else
                    if($i == 1)
                        $sql = $sql_videos;
                    else
                        if($i == 2)
                            $sql = $sql_audio;
                        else
                            if($i == 3)
                                $sql = $sql_documents;

                $result = $connect->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $data = array();
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $public = $row['public'];
                        $link = $row['link'];
                        $upload_time = $row['upload_time'];
                        $data[$indexOfSuggests] = array($id, $user_id, $name, $public, $link, $upload_time);
                        array_push($collectData, $data[$indexOfSuggests]);
                        $indexOfSuggests++;
                    }
                    $new_index = $indexOfSuggests;
                }
                else {
                    // keine ergebnisse
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($collectData);
        }
    }
}
else {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
```

}

So i got it but in a really uncool way. So the last thing I have to do is to order the array values by date.

Answer (score 0):

here is new fix :)

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dataType'])) {
    switch ($_POST['dataType']) {
        case 'start':
            $data_type = 'pictures,videos,audio,documents';
            break;
        case 'picture':
            $data_type = 'pictures';
            break;
        case 'videos':
            $data_type = 'videos';
            break;
        case 'audio':
            $data_type = 'audio';
            break;
        case 'documents':
            $data_type = 'documents';
            break;
        default:
            $data_type = '';
    }

    function get_list ($sql,&$list) {
        // Create connection
        $connect = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($connect->connect_error) {
            die(1);
        } else {
            $result = $connect->query($sql);
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $user_id = $row['user_id'];
                $name = $row['name'];
                $public = $row['public'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                $upload_time = $row['upload_time'];
                $list[] = array($id, $user_id, $name, $public, $link, $upload_time);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($data_type)) {
        $list = array();
        $userId = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['userId']);
        if ($_POST['dataType'] !== 'start') {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $data_type . " WHERE user_id = " . $userId;
            get_list($sql,$list);
        } else {
            $data_types = explode(',',$data_type);
            foreach($data_types as $type) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $type . " WHERE user_id = " . $userId;
                get_list($sql,$list);
            }
        }

        if(empty($list))
            die(0);
        else
            echo json_encode($list);

    } else {
        header("Location: http://google.com");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: please check update, it should works - and also double check **Spelling**

Comment: works fine but i got no value from the DB it has to do with the sql

Comment: Just updated, I did multi queries and insert into list

Comment: fatal error on line $result = $connect->query($sql);

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.